# Switching keys and values in a dictionary in python with multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dictionary like so (data from geonamescache):

```
{'3041563': {'geonameid': 3041563,
  'name': 'Andorra la Vella',
  'latitude': 42.50779,
  'longitude': 1.52109,
  'countrycode': 'AD',
  'population': 20430,
  'timezone': 'Europe/Andorra',
  'admin1code': '07'},
 '290594': {'geonameid': 290594,
  'name': 'Umm Al Quwain City',
  'latitude': 25.56473,
  'longitude': 55.55517,
  'countrycode': 'AE',
  'population': 62747,
  'timezone': 'Asia/Dubai',
  'admin1code': '07'},
 '291074': {'geonameid': 291074,
  'name': 'Ras Al Khaimah City',
  'latitude': 25.78953,
  'longitude': 55.9432,
  'countrycode': 'AE',
  'population': 351943,
  'timezone': 'Asia/Dubai',
  'admin1code': '05'},....
```

How can I switch the keys with the value 'name', for all items in dict?
Meaning the city name will become the key for each item.

Expected output:

```
{'Andorra la Vella': {'geonameid': 3041563,
  'latitude': 42.50779,
  'longitude': 1.52109,
  'countrycode': 'AD',
  'population': 20430,
  'timezone': 'Europe/Andorra',
  'admin1code': '07'},
 'Umm Al Quwain City': {'geonameid': 290594,
  'latitude': 25.56473,
  'longitude': 55.55517,
  'countrycode': 'AE',
  'population': 62747,
  'timezone': 'Asia/Dubai',
  'admin1code': '07'},
 'Ras Al Khaimah City': {'geonameid': 291074,
  'latitude': 25.78953,
  'longitude': 55.9432,
  'countrycode': 'AE',
  'population': 351943,
  'timezone': 'Asia/Dubai',
  'admin1code': '05'},....
```

Comment: What do you mean by switch keys? Please provide the expected output

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to do it? That seems like a very basic dictionary operation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for an output like this?

```
{'Andorra la Vella': {'admin1code': '07',
  'countrycode': 'AD',
  'geonameid': 3041563,
  'latitude': 42.50779,
  'longitude': 1.52109,
  'name': 'Andorra la Vella',
  'population': 20430,
  'timezone': 'Europe/Andorra'},
 'Ras Al Khaimah City': {'admin1code': '05',
  'countrycode': 'AE',
  'geonameid': 291074,
  'latitude': 25.78953,
  'longitude': 55.9432,
  'name': 'Ras Al Khaimah City',
  'population': 351943,
  'timezone': 'Asia/Dubai'},
 'Umm Al Quwain City': {'admin1code': '07',
  'countrycode': 'AE',
  'geonameid': 290594,
  'latitude': 25.56473,
  'longitude': 55.55517,
  'name': 'Umm Al Quwain City',
  'population': 62747,
  'timezone': 'Asia/Dubai'}}
```

If so, you can create a new dictionary of this format from the existing one. Here is one way you can do it, where `dicc` is your existing dictionary.

```
newdic = {}
for key, val in dicc.items():
    newdic[val['name']] = val

print(newdic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reassign the values as the keys:

```
data = ...  # Your data here
for geocode, area in data.items():
    cityname = area["name"]
    area[cityname] = "name"
    del area["name"]  # if you don’t want the ‘name’ key anymore
    data[geocode] = area
```

Comment: Actually, the question is pretty vague, so @Shruteesh Raman Iyer’s answer could be the correct answer instead.